# How to wait in a XCTest for T seconds without timeout error?

Tags: ios, swift, timeout, wait, xctest

I want to delay progression of a test for T seconds, without generating a timeout.

First I tried the obvious:

```
sleep(5)
XCTAssert(<test if state is correct after this delay>)
```

But that failed.

Then I tried:

```
let promise = expectation(description: "Just wait 5 seconds")
waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) in
    promise.fulfill()

    XCTAssert(<test if state is correct after this delay>)
}
```

My `XCTAssert()` now succeeded.  But `waitForExpectations()` failed with a timeout.

This is according to the documentation of [`XCTest` wait functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1500748-waitforexpectations) saying:

> Timeout is always treated as a test failure.

What are my options?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use [XCTWaiter.wait](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter) functions.

For example:

```swift
let exp = expectation(description: "Test after 5 seconds")
let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [exp], timeout: 5.0)
if result == XCTWaiter.Result.timedOut {
    XCTAssert(<test if state is correct after this delay>)
} else {
    XCTFail("Delay interrupted")
}
```

Comment: (1) Where should I call my method to test (2) How to set the expectation as fulfil?

Answer (score 30):

If you know how much time something will take and simply want to wait that duration before continuing the test, you can use this one line:

```
_ = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation(description: "Wait for n seconds")], timeout: 2.0)
```

Answer (score 13):

What best worked for me was:

```
let timeInSeconds = 2.0 // time you need for other tasks to be finished
let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Your expectation")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeInSeconds) {
    expectation.fulfill()
}    

wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeInSeconds + 1.0) // make sure it's more than what you used in AsyncAfter call.

//do your XCTAssertions here
XCTAssertNotNil(value)
```