# XCTWaiter.wait() timeout seems to take longer sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, wait, xctest, xctwaiter

[To add delays in my tests I implemented this:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50247929/1971013)

```
func execute(after: TimeInterval, testBlock: () -> Void) {
    let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation(description: "Delayed Test")], timeout: after)

    if result == XCTWaiter.Result.timedOut {
        testBlock()
    } else {
        XCTFail("Delay interrupted.")
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a test:

```
func testExecute() {
    var i = 1

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.40) {
        i = 2
    }

    execute(after: 0.20) {
        XCTAssert(i == 1)
    }

    execute(after: 0.15) {
        XCTAssert(i == 1)   // Fails once every three or four runs.
    }

    execute(after: 0.06) {  // Never fails.
        XCTAssert(i == 2)
    }
}
```

Why does this second `XCTAssert()` fail regularly?

This is the only thing running on my simulator.  You'd expect some jitter, but shouldn't that stay with 1 or 2 times the system clock period of 1/60s?

Comment: I try your code, its only fail when i using break points.

Comment: @A.Munzer Of course. I didn't have breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that delays may take up to considerably longer (up to 200ms in this 2011 experiment: http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/).

Must take sufficient margins when using this `execute(after:testBlock:)` function.