# UI Test for SwiftUI app does't find element with set accessibilityIdentifier after a timer has passed

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

**The app:**

The app has a tag cloud that adds and removes tags as `Text` views every few seconds to a `ZStack` using `ForEach` triggered by an `ObservableObject`. The `ZStack` has an `accessibilityIdentifier` set.

**The UI test:**

In the UI Test I have set a `XCTWaiter` first. After a certain period of time has passed I then check if the `XCUIElement` (`ZStack`) with the `accessibilityIdentifier` exists.
After that I query the `ZStack` `XCUIElement` for all descendants of type `.staticText`
I also query the `XCUIApplication` for its descendants of type `.staticText`

**The following issues:**

When the `XCTWaiter` is set too wait too long. It does not find the `ZStack` `XCUIElement` with its identifier anymore.

If the `XCTWaiter` is set to a low wait time or removed the `ZStack` `XCUIElement` will be found. But it will never find its descendants of type `.staticText`. They do exists though because I can find them as descendant of `XCUIApplication` itself.

**My assumption:**

I assume that the `ZStack` with its identifier can only be found by the tests as long as it does not have descendants. And because it doesn't have any descendants at this moment yet, querying the `ZStack` `XCUIElement` for its descendants later also fails because the `XCUIElement` seems to only represent the `ZStack` at the time it was captured.

Or maybe I have attached the `accessibilityIdentifier` for the `ZStack` at the wrong place or SwiftUI is removing it as soon as there are descendants and I should add identifiers to the descendants only. But that would mean I can only query descendants from `XCUIApplication` itself and never from another XCUIElement? That would make the `.children(matching:)` quite useless.

**Here is the code for a single view iOS app in SwiftUI with tests enabled.**

**MyAppUITests.swift**

```
import XCTest

class MyAppUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testingTheInitialView() throws {
        
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        let exp = expectation(description: "Waiting for tag cloud to be populated.")
        _ = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [exp], timeout: 1) // 1. If timeout is set higher
        
        let tagCloud = app.otherElements["TagCloud"]
        XCTAssert(tagCloud.exists) // 2. The ZStack with the identifier "TagCloud" does not exist anymore.
        
        let tagsDescendingFromTagCloud = tagCloud.descendants(matching: .staticText)
        XCTAssert(tagsDescendingFromTagCloud.firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 2)) // 4. However, it never finds the tags as the descendants of the tagCloud
        
        let tagsDescendingFromApp = app.descendants(matching: .staticText)
        XCTAssert(tagsDescendingFromApp.firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 2)) // 3. It does find the created tags here.
        
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @ObservedObject var tagModel = TagModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(tagModel.tags, id: \.self) { label in
                TagView(label: label)
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                self.tagModel.addNextTag()
                if tagModel.tags.count > 3 {
                    self.tagModel.removeOldestTag()
                }
            }
        }.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 4.0))
        .accessibilityIdentifier("TagCloud")
    }
}

class TagModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tags = [String]()
    
    func addNextTag() {
        tags.append(String( Date().timeIntervalSince1970 ))
    }
    func removeOldestTag() {
        tags.remove(at: 0)
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    @State private var show: Bool = true
    @State private var position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: 50..<250), y: Int.random(in: 100..<200))
    
    let label: String
    
    var body: some View {
        let text = Text(label)
            .position(position)
            .opacity(show ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            .onAppear {
                show.toggle()
            }
        return text
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it looks like you are *NOT* fulfilling the XCTestExpectation you set up with:

`let exp = expectation(description: "Waiting...")`

In the past, I have used the XCTestExpecation for asynchronous code to signal completion. So like in this example where I set up the XCTestExpectation and provide a description, then made a network call, and on completion of the network call ran `exp.fulfill()`.

```
let exp = expectation(description: "Recieved success message after uploading onboarding model")
            
 _ = UserController.upsertUserOnboardingModel().subscribe(onNext: { (response) in
    
   expectation.fulfill()
    
   }, onError: { (error) in
    
      print("\(#function): \(error)")
      XCTFail()
    
   })
    
wait(for: [exp], timeout: 10)
```

Steps should be: Create Expectation -> Fulfil Expectation within X seconds.
I don't see any `exp.fulfill()` in your provided code so looks like that is a missing step.

Proposed Solutions:

A. So what you could do is fulfill your `exp` at some point during the number of
seconds specified in the `timeout: x`.

B. Or you want just wanting a delay you could use `sleep(3)`

C. Or if you want to wait for existence pick an element and use `.waitForExistence(timeout: Int)`
Example: `XCTAssert(app.searchFields["Search for cars here"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))`

Comment: To A. and B. the XCTWaiter I've setup does nothing more than sleep(), replacing it with sleep does not change the result at all. :/ See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65657873/12764795 C. If I wait for existence it doesn't solve the problem either. Assuming there are other waitForExistence or delays before that test will also fail at the same place.